# The intersection of locally connected spaces is locally connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I am trying to prove that:

Let $A$, $B$ subspaces X , if $A$ and $B$ are locally connected then $A \cap B$ is locally connected

but I can't prove or disprove. I don't show my attempt because I have nothing concrete, can someone help me with some hint ?

My definition is "A space X is locally connected  if and only if for each $x \in X$ and $V$ neighborhood of x exist a  connected  neighborhood C such that $ x \in C \subset V$ "

Comment: Try first writing down the definition of locally connected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define $$A=[0,1]×\{0\}\bigcup_n A_n$$ where 
$$A_n=\{t(0,1/n)+(1-t)(1/n,0))\mid 0\le t\le 1\}$$
And $$B=[-1,0]×\{0\}\bigcup_n B_n$$ where
$$B_n=\{t(0,1/n)+(1-t)(-1/n,0))\mid 0\le t\le 1\}$$
$A$ and $B$ are locally connected, but $A\cap B$ is the convergent sequence
$$\{(0,0)\}\cup\left(0,\frac1n\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$$

It is of course true if $A$ and $B$ are open. In that case $B$ does not have to be locally connected.

Answer (score 2):

A and B need maybe to be open, it's a local property.
Then you take a point $x \in A\cap B$, a neighborhood in A which contains a connex neighborhood, the same in B, and take the intersection.